# Linux apt-get status meaning?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When using apt-get in Linux, one often comes across status updates like:

```
Get: www.somesite.com/.../...
Hit: www.somesite.com/.../...
```

I would like to know what these statuses actually mean. I suspect that the 'Get' might be http requests, but Wikipedia doesn't list 'Hit' as an http request and it doesn't make sense for there to be two different types of requests performing similar actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the apt [source](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/acddd9188c21c2e13aff5cea3a82f2d01aff788b/apt-private/acqprogress.cc) `Get` is the status for actually grabbing a new file, whereas `Hit` is using the currently cached file.